# Firebase rules - write value only if the user is registered to specific child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure:

[image]

I want to add a custom `.write` role to `liveLocations`.

If the user is "registered" under `games` >> gamekey >> `players` he can add only his value in `liveLocations` >>  gamekey .

The problem here is that gamekey is a unique id and not a constant so I **can't** do something like :

```
"liveLocations": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "-LA3H25IA1hiyxL-TCWE": {
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
```

Is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from the docs is that you can use a variable there, so you could use `$liveLocation` in place of the fixed value `"-LA3H25IA1hiyxL-TCWE"`

```
"liveLocations": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$liveLocation": {
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/?hl=es-419#location